# Seeking template for the generation of EN16931 (ZugFERD) compliant E-invoice xml

Tags: xml, django-templates, invoice, zugferd

Our small company is being required to supply EU-compliant E-invoices. I have found the Python package `factur-x`, and the factur-x plug-in for libreoffice. Unfortunately the latter generates only minimal factur-X invoices, and our customers are telling us that these are insufficient.

Can anybody help me with pointers either to other open-source software, or to English-language examples or descriptions  of the required xml?

Ideally, a Django template that could convert a  Python dict or suchlike context into the relevant xml, for merging into a pdf invoice (which factur-x can do). Any other macro or template language would do.  But I'll take any help I can get. I can't read standards documents written in German!

Answer (score 1):

Working on the same topic at the moment.

For generating the xml with Python, take a look at this library:
https://github.com/invinet/python-en16931

Unfortunately this library seems to be not maintained since the last years but can serve as a good starting point.

With the `factur-x` library you have already found you can merge the xml to the pdf but keep in mind that you will need the PDF/A3 format to make the invoice compliant. So either the original PDF already has the A3 archive format or - the way I prefer - is to use ghostscript to merge the xml.
See https://ghostscript.com/zugferd.html

EDIT:

---

Also take a look in the xsd-folder that comes with the `factur-x`-Library - there you have the XML schema description files needed to create a compliant xml.